# getting the row data in ListView before the user edit it in a ListView with custom cursor adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have a ListView with extended CursorAdapter.
The view of each row is three ImageButton views for edit,delete and save two EditText views.
The two EditText views show strings from the cursor data, and they are disabled by default.
When the user click edit ImageButton the two EditText views enabled and the save ImageButton is shown to let user edit the strings and let him save them.
Then I want to update my table row with the strings which are present when the user click save ImageButton.
I am updating the row of the table by using the old/current strings present before the user click the edit ImageButton and edit them, because my method uses the SqLiteDatabase.update method to update the row, and I use the column name and the old/current string to specify which row will update in the table.
I have two questions:
how can I get/save the old/current strings before the user change them?
how to disable all rows of ListView when user clicks a button and enable them when he clicks another button?
My custom view for ListView rows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/save_edited_entry"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_save_black_24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:focusable="false"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/answer_field"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/question_field"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/edit_entry"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_create_white_24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/delete_entry"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_clear_black_24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:focusable="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My extended CursorAdpater:

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
        public CustomCursorAdapter( Context context, Cursor cursor, int          flags ) {
            super(context,cursor,flags);
        }
        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
            final EditText editQuestion, editAnswer;
            editQuestion = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.question_field);
            editAnswer = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.answer_field);
            editQuestion.setText(cursor.getString(1));
            editAnswer.setText(cursor.getString(2));
            final ImageButton  saveEditedEntry, editEntry, deleteEntry;
            editEntry = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_entry);
            deleteEntry = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_entry);
            saveEditedEntry = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.save_edited_entry);

            editEntry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    editQuestion.setEnabled(true);
                    editAnswer.setEnabled(true);
                    saveEditedEntry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            saveEditedEntry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            final View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.aspect_entries_spinner, parent, false);
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **How can I get/save the old/current strings before the user change them?**

You can access the old values of the question and the answer from the cursor because you have not committed the modification made.

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
            final EditText editQuestion, editAnswer;
            editQuestion = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.question_field);
            editAnswer = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.answer_field);
            final question = cursor.getString(1);
            final answer = cursor.getString(2);
            editQuestion.setText(cursor.getString(1));
            editAnswer.setText(cursor.getString(2));
            final ImageButton  saveEditedEntry, editEntry, deleteEntry;
            editEntry = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_entry);
            deleteEntry = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_entry);
            saveEditedEntry = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.save_edited_entry);

            editEntry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    editQuestion.setEnabled(true);
                    editAnswer.setEnabled(true);
                    saveEditedEntry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            saveEditedEntry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //You can use the question and answer here
                }
            });
        }
```

2. **How to prevent the user from clicking the edit ImageButton for more that one row in my ListView**

This is from top of my head, you can keep track of the row currently being edited in your cursor adapter. If there is any such row, you can prevent editing of other rows in the list view. And then set the value this variable to null once done editing.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer of the first question have worked very good.